# validation in reducer in redux

Tags: validation, reactjs, redux

this question is about where to put validation of an form element in redux.  I feeeeel as though I should have an onValueChange event that dispatches an action to the reducer that validates and updates both the value ( invalid or valid as it may be ) as well as the "isValid" property on state so that that element can then display an error.

Conversely, I could do the validation in the action, and if it fails just dispatch a failure action instead.

One note is that i do prefer the anonymous function nomenclature to extending the react.component.

I guess I should change then name of this to where is the proper place to put validation in the redux flow.

Comment: I'd say "it depends". I prefer to take care of the actual validation in the event handler of the component it concerns, forgetting about Redux for a moment, and dispatch the appropriate action depending on the result. I feel that reducers shouldn't be involved until you actually change the state of the application.

Comment: Or you could do the validation in your component. Intermediate state doesn't belong in Redux imo. Save the state in Redux once you submit a valid form.

Comment: How can you put any bussiness logic into reducers if you are not allowed do "reject" the update and trigger a different action instead?
If the designers allowed the reducers to return an action you could, for example, validate the form data against other object of the same type in the store while they are readily available (for example to ensure the email of the user being added is unique) and then do the changes (or not) and trigger either an action to clear the form or an action to report a duplicate email. But that would make too much sense for React.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep the validation in your component. I hear a lot of "keep all state in redux", but I try to only keep what I absolutely need in redux. Use component state with a error property and if your validation fails set the state on the error property. As well, redux forms: http://redux-form.com/4.2.0/#/?_k=mhjui4 is a good library for simple and complex forms.

Comment: Right, I guess this was a while ago, but I have come to the same conclusion that there is state that is appropriate for the component and state that is appropriate for redux, and other state as well.  So I went with component controlling it's own state until it's time to submit.